# Calling e.preventDefault() Stops TouchEvents from Scrolling Page, but any Additional Click Listeners Don't Fire

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tab that slides up and it can be closed with user based touch events for mobile devices. I got this sliding tab/modal to work well and it is a piece of code that is dynamically appended to the DOM.

Once this code is dynamically appended to the DOM, I also dynamically add certain event listeners. I got super stuck when I realized that my click event listener wasn't firing.

It got even more confusing when I noticed I could use `.click()` on the target element and it would fire but clicking on it would not work.

I figured out why this happened and it turns out that calling `e.preventDefault()` inside of my click event listeners was causing my click event not to work.

I am stuck on how to move forward here because `e.preventDefault()` keeps my page from scrolling when the tab is being swiped, but it is causing other events not to fire that are dynamically added inside of the tab.

**1.)** Setting passive to true stops e.preventDefault from being called and without e.preventDefault(), whole page scrolls. **Is there a way to stop page from scrolling without calling e.preventDefault()?**

2.) **Why does e.preventDefault stop inner click event from running?**

3.) Why does click() work still?

4.) How could this be better written that the page doesnt scroll and events can be dynamically added?

Here is a runnable example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uruonq?file=index.js

```js
function openTab(config) {
  const { onRender } = config

  document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="swipe-tab">
      <div class="swipe-tab__content></div>
    </div>
  `)

  const swipeTab = document.querySelector('.swipe-tab')

  /**
   * just assume these functions make the tab follow
   * the users finger
  */
  swipeTab.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
     e.preventDefault()
  })
  swipeTab.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
    // e.preventDefault() stops the whole page from scrolling
     
     e.preventDefault()
  })
  swipeTab.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
     e.preventDefault()
  })

  if (onRender) onRender()
}


openTab({
  onRender() {
    document.querySelector('.swipe-tab__content').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
       <button class="test-btn"></button>
    `)

    const btn = document.querySelector('.swipe-tab .test-btn')

    btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
      // this will not log. e.preventDefault() stops this from working
      console.log('clicked')
    })

   // this still works for some reason
   btn.click()
  }
})
```

Comment: Why are you using `touchmove` events?  Aren't they low level events that get involved in all sorts of higher level events?  (i,e,  Both scroll events and click events (and a bunch of other things) may be prevented because they both typically will happen in the same stream as a touchmove

Comment: I have a tab that is swipeable, and just like in many native apps, and some good sites, the tab follows the users finger. I could make a modal with a close icon that when clicked has a transition and closes the modal but I wanted the user to be able to swipe down to close it.

Comment: Ok, so you're going to need to build some tracking into your code instead of just using `.preventDefault()` for everything.  You need to be able to tell the difference between one type of swipe and another and only prevent propagation for the appropriate events.

Comment: Can you give a bare bones example, not of the exact functionality to move a tab around, I already understand how to use these events, I do NOT understand what you mean with tracking, or the why behind it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use CSS to prevent the scrolling behavior?  For example, you could set the body to have a position fixed.

#### Demo (definitely not production code)

Instructions:  Scroll to the buttons, click the FIX button FIRST.  The page can no longer scroll.  Click the UNFIX button and the page scrolls freely again.  I added lots of content in there to point out that you'd need to keep track of the current scroll position before setting the position to fixed, and restore it after.

```js
const fix = document.getElementById('fixed');
const unfix = document.getElementById('unfixed');
const bodyEl = document.body; 
const docEl = document.documentElement;

fix.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const top = docEl.scrollTop;
  bodyEl.style.top = `${top * -1}px`;
  bodyEl.style.position = 'fixed';
})
unfix.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const top = bodyEl.style.top;
  const scrollTopValue = top && top !== 'auto' ? parseInt(top.match(/\d+/gi)[0]) : 0;
  bodyEl.removeAttribute('style');
  docEl.scrollTop = scrollTopValue;
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse dolorem repellendus, odit, iste labore exercitationem consequatur, placeat autem dolorum rerum voluptas possimus non laboriosam neque perferendis sequi architecto quos officiis?</p>
<p>At vel doloremque perferendis optio molestias architecto ratione laboriosam! Consequatur rem asperiores numquam quia accusamus ipsam voluptate modi? Nemo in libero dicta quisquam similique sed veniam totam labore nam delectus.</p>
<p>Minus corporis labore commodi quae saepe nobis, unde impedit est pariatur vero quos similique tenetur deleniti architecto odio veritatis dolorum nulla officia illo eos incidunt ullam! Impedit quibusdam officiis molestias!</p>
<p>Expedita similique, repellendus labore error asperiores suscipit mollitia aperiam molestias fugit nihil quae ipsa officia nemo blanditiis quidem tenetur id dolor sapiente quibusdam sit laudantium voluptatum! Similique eaque repellat iste!</p>
<p>Cumque quod unde totam neque minima nemo, similique praesentium nulla, ea voluptas accusamus at mollitia, delectus deserunt. Aspernatur deserunt laboriosam non quod eos aut, expedita veritatis, perspiciatis modi culpa rerum.</p>
<p>Nostrum soluta illum sit eveniet, consectetur dolor molestiae, culpa aspernatur labore dicta earum iste doloremque quisquam ea et laudantium optio? Eaque ratione rerum optio, quas ad dolorum ullam harum qui?</p>
<p>Nisi voluptas exercitationem eligendi temporibus, sequi tempora dolor rem, maxime dignissimos ut placeat aliquid obcaecati nobis! Eligendi recusandae tempora, a impedit magni sunt nam non, deleniti ab blanditiis consectetur consequatur.</p>
<p>Voluptatum ipsa id maxime necessitatibus distinctio delectus deserunt, nesciunt officiis fugit labore doloremque, voluptatem iusto mollitia soluta, eligendi ducimus tenetur repudiandae dolorem aspernatur corrupti velit! Sed, dolorum. Vitae, similique quos!</p>
<p>Autem id temporibus doloribus veniam, corporis at nihil consectetur ut obcaecati iusto? Illum distinctio, nisi magni itaque quidem ratione ab esse porro neque hic laboriosam a suscipit aliquid ipsam odit.</p>
<p>Dicta et ducimus est consectetur tenetur at officiis, deleniti hic porro sunt? Ipsam, sed. Ut commodi recusandae quasi quis, natus adipisci corporis exercitationem, rerum perferendis voluptatibus at voluptate. Culpa, corrupti.</p>
<p>Ut aliquam dolorum tempore, eius esse libero repudiandae amet laboriosam nihil ipsum veniam assumenda neque fugit ipsa accusantium veritatis consequuntur exercitationem, ipsam unde, ad natus. Dignissimos commodi magni aliquam ab.</p>
<p>Dolorum, dolore porro. Enim ipsum eaque iste delectus dolor sint, aperiam veritatis soluta odio a provident, exercitationem expedita est, ipsam eligendi quidem? Sequi nostrum ratione nemo necessitatibus est nesciunt nobis.</p>
<p>Rerum enim reiciendis nihil officia aut ex, recusandae exercitationem dolores eos ipsum quos vero, minus aliquam et commodi! Commodi repellat debitis expedita magnam vel odio nihil dolorum, eos eligendi recusandae?</p>
<p>Culpa quasi quaerat quia atque? Temporibus officia sint consequatur animi rerum, molestias accusamus quod veniam in numquam. Provident quasi perspiciatis quos, inventore sint eius eos voluptate dolorem suscipit enim laboriosam.</p>
<p>Consectetur atque distinctio maiores necessitatibus minima provident voluptas sequi culpa optio enim eaque, ex sunt totam. In ea sequi fuga perspiciatis recusandae, asperiores quae, sunt ab adipisci quisquam, placeat laborum.</p>
<p>Sapiente iusto, quas labore possimus et recusandae molestias explicabo illo beatae! Iste culpa nihil excepturi est ratione vel, non, libero, cumque inventore maxime labore facere iusto sequi sint quos consequatur!</p>
<p>Commodi quo, in debitis nobis eum quaerat architecto eius laboriosam eveniet dicta tempore culpa nulla soluta dignissimos ab eligendi deleniti, doloribus amet voluptatem facilis officia iure rem dolorem. Magni, obcaecati!</p>
<p>Molestias voluptatem incidunt quas molestiae debitis facere praesentium dicta dolorum unde saepe aperiam quam odit magni in, explicabo sit nesciunt soluta, commodi dolor. Quod exercitationem quidem voluptas consequuntur praesentium saepe.</p>
<p>Eos accusamus ab voluptates quidem incidunt molestiae, nam delectus tempore libero cupiditate, labore doloribus qui praesentium fuga natus ratione iusto quia minima aut! Voluptatibus ut, asperiores velit quod nihil porro.</p>
<p>Porro quidem magni earum id assumenda odio minima. Aspernatur aut dolore quidem laudantium, ipsum modi dolores odio at unde. Pariatur eos reiciendis dolores accusamus similique commodi minus laboriosam rerum ratione.</p>
<p>Magni, ex possimus, recusandae molestias totam numquam laudantium quis sed placeat quod inventore? Perferendis facere, amet dignissimos repellat officiis ea mollitia pariatur voluptates, minima, ipsa provident veritatis explicabo dolore dolorem!</p>
<p>Sed, nostrum? Quia nisi ratione quam nesciunt rem blanditiis sunt tempore deserunt quos numquam exercitationem repellat libero quae nostrum nihil repudiandae dolorum eius magni, minus qui architecto doloribus ad. Corporis.</p>
<p>Eos minima, aspernatur deserunt excepturi ipsum iusto? Amet molestiae expedita magni cupiditate, ratione iste modi laudantium soluta, possimus deserunt commodi sit perspiciatis totam ut alias odio eius sunt nam culpa.</p>
<button id="fixed">Click to fix</button>
<button id="unfixed">Click to unfix</button>
<p>Tempora alias in laudantium quos officiis officia illum voluptatum facere sed voluptatem nisi id ex similique placeat ipsa dolores molestias consequatur consectetur, rerum minus! Distinctio dolore commodi nihil similique? Excepturi.</p>
<p>Tenetur repellat dolorem adipisci aspernatur? Expedita cupiditate quaerat, libero ad iusto in vel suscipit magni possimus aliquid culpa soluta rem sunt? Autem ratione ipsam quia quo facilis rem veritatis perferendis?</p>
<p>Culpa libero quia et voluptate rem, magnam iusto nesciunt voluptatibus non dolores voluptatum nihil aperiam, nemo neque. Ad asperiores sequi pariatur dolor rerum illo nisi nam temporibus explicabo, blanditiis hic.</p>
<p>Numquam, officia aut! Officiis non delectus error cum a voluptatem consequatur expedita quaerat amet provident soluta, totam facere incidunt voluptatum nam at. Quia, asperiores molestiae. Quis libero odit quisquam ipsa.</p>
<p>Earum hic deleniti, sit ea consequatur vitae dolorem facere deserunt sunt doloremque commodi, voluptate perspiciatis. Illum dolore temporibus hic blanditiis repudiandae fugiat natus? Amet architecto totam inventore asperiores aliquid molestiae?</p>
<p>Dolore dignissimos nesciunt enim exercitationem, eligendi nihil itaque laudantium aperiam adipisci tenetur ipsam esse eos, perferendis, at maiores. Esse facilis tenetur suscipit iste atque officia, beatae fuga ut iure laborum.</p>
<p>Ipsum voluptatum tempore adipisci sed! Perferendis est eius sed odio fuga. Ea culpa, modi optio laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt, necessitatibus tenetur corporis officia libero quis dolores iure obcaecati ab voluptatem quae.</p>
<p>Voluptate, dignissimos dolor nam animi et eligendi commodi nesciunt minima veritatis facilis ullam hic aperiam perspiciatis itaque molestias ex laboriosam a, deleniti enim ratione autem magnam? Iure obcaecati nisi aspernatur.</p>
<p>Praesentium harum, cum quibusdam aliquid sed laboriosam facilis ipsa iure officia modi dicta possimus consequatur adipisci tempore qui natus eaque beatae laudantium illo nihil iste blanditiis architecto eius. Tenetur, molestias!</p>
<p>Mollitia molestiae voluptatem vero, sed quod aliquid possimus quae quas minima neque facere cumque, dicta temporibus cum ipsum culpa minus? Commodi numquam architecto maiores recusandae sapiente ratione dolore quam facilis!</p>
<p>Esse quis quibusdam quos saepe dicta sequi, animi iure nostrum officia qui, aliquam a assumenda reiciendis odit soluta nesciunt amet ea? Voluptas saepe deleniti quae. Ullam maiores aliquid excepturi repellat!</p>
<p>Fuga nulla quae, ex eaque sit labore officiis error? Saepe, laborum! Impedit mollitia quidem perspiciatis eaque, quas velit sint expedita eum facilis veritatis ad quia dicta ab, labore quos temporibus?</p>
<p>Assumenda odio voluptatibus nulla quaerat temporibus, rerum veritatis consectetur ullam dolores aspernatur praesentium sint et delectus dicta. Mollitia repellat officia officiis explicabo nostrum deserunt ipsam, minima, at earum facere laudantium!</p>
<p>Veniam, labore odit. Eligendi ex voluptates ad ut magnam est et, praesentium, facere reiciendis libero sunt officia officiis velit? Aspernatur blanditiis sequi modi cumque molestiae, tenetur autem voluptatibus explicabo repellat?</p>
<p>Necessitatibus aperiam quo maiores, laudantium ipsum vero consectetur nam mollitia obcaecati commodi fuga doloribus quae repudiandae magni in dolorum rem quisquam ea porro perferendis animi quas nostrum dicta dolor. Eum.</p>
<p>Tenetur sit inventore, iure adipisci, aspernatur repellat odio quas, neque minima quae praesentium itaque excepturi perspiciatis? Dignissimos cumque, ad quae quidem magni at magnam totam vel quaerat nesciunt corrupti placeat.</p>
<p>Suscipit repudiandae fugiat harum iusto cumque minus atque consequuntur voluptatibus? Aliquam neque doloribus magnam repellat voluptates incidunt suscipit, eos aut, vero officiis voluptas possimus ipsam itaque quam hic optio nemo.</p>
<p>Veritatis, harum quaerat tempore sed nisi doloribus molestiae itaque officia voluptas officiis accusantium commodi totam incidunt illo odio saepe! Facere fugit beatae adipisci dolor, laboriosam odit laudantium cupiditate quas nesciunt.</p>
<p>Iure deleniti vitae illo, est repellat quo aliquid officia dolor vero quisquam nihil. Pariatur nobis corporis eius nemo, adipisci incidunt repellendus odio voluptate eligendi esse fugiat maxime asperiores perferendis. Eius.</p>
<p>Provident mollitia similique, praesentium illum quidem voluptates iure libero tempora iste ullam fugit distinctio deserunt dicta ducimus qui ex voluptatum reiciendis officiis quos enim! Natus illo voluptatum iusto obcaecati quibusdam?</p>
<p>Nisi delectus voluptatum necessitatibus quod iste? Molestias velit rerum quibusdam itaque perferendis nesciunt culpa eos quaerat perspiciatis. Unde corporis voluptas culpa dignissimos nam velit autem. Sit eveniet ex tempora autem.</p>
<p>Rerum culpa aspernatur modi ipsum sapiente voluptas, delectus voluptatem eligendi eius. Quidem, culpa suscipit, veniam officia consequatur perspiciatis debitis, nihil at ab iure necessitatibus atque laudantium et eius autem quasi?</p>
<p>Provident cumque, veniam harum vero voluptatem eligendi, saepe nulla temporibus nihil similique fugit! Maxime quis ducimus deleniti, sint inventore tempora adipisci exercitationem consequuntur saepe iusto facere totam mollitia reiciendis fugit.</p>
<p>Enim quae sunt eius consectetur, aliquam ratione dolorum tenetur molestias eaque et animi, impedit alias omnis id optio in amet reprehenderit quam odio porro ipsum. Pariatur voluptatem earum aliquid nostrum?</p>
<p>Asperiores exercitationem officia sapiente odit architecto error saepe autem non aperiam deserunt enim unde vitae suscipit neque, nulla incidunt ratione possimus nemo dicta mollitia? Ullam nostrum ipsum suscipit repellat tenetur.</p>
<p>Possimus porro labore, voluptatum saepe inventore repellat nisi, natus impedit illo tempora nostrum corporis recusandae ipsam explicabo qui quae dolor, consequatur aliquid beatae ad voluptate voluptas. Sunt omnis dolorem tempora.</p>
<p>Minus, odio? Inventore, magni. Laudantium perspiciatis aut quas molestiae quae alias neque natus voluptate eveniet odit exercitationem, officiis, aliquid excepturi nihil. Et architecto modi, fugit fuga adipisci assumenda nesciunt! Neque?</p>
```

Comment: I know this trick already. I have ran into issues in the past with modals on ios. When the body is fixed it still moves when the tab is swiped. Actually the whole page moves down like it's going to be refreshed

Comment: Even if you set `touch-action: none;` (and `pointer-events` as well I guess) on the body simultaneously?

Comment: I think I just got this to work, I will have to do some more testing but I think it should work. `e.preventDefault()` only needs to be called on touch move and with this the click event listeners will work. I just tried using touch-action none and it seems to be keeping everything locked in place. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't think of using a css property here.